# Suppose you’re given two mutually exclusive events A and B, with P(A) = 1/4 and P(B) = 1/3.

Tags: probability

What is P(A(complement)intersect with B)

and vice versa.

since they are mutually exclusive they cant intersect so what does that mean for the complement

Answer (score 0):

$A^{c} \cap B=B$ because $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive.